# Java JFrame Resizing

Tags: java, resize, event-listener

I know I can use `componentResized` to listen for when the user resizes a window. This isn't a very nice solution. If I do this and add a `resize()` method for the children components, then it waits until the user finishes the resizing before it calls the `resize()` method. Is there a way to resize the child elements as the resize happens?

Comment: Using appropriate layout managers, it should not be necessary to manually resize components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The listener with `componentResized()` is the nice solution. Using listener in swing isn't a bad solution at all.

You can see the solution you want on [oracle.com](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/componentlistener.html)

Comment: My problem is, if the user resizes the window from 600px to 800px, the components inside will not resize until the user has finished resizing. It looks damn terrible. I am seeking something that will resize the components with the window.

Comment: usually component are resizing at the same time as the container (see the example given in the answer).

Comment: I was adding the listener to my window and not my JPanel, that was my problem.